# Problem linking shared library for python on Linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ctypes

While I am trying to set up my code on linux VM. The library had been installed correctly and I could reference it and run smooth with C code. However, while I am trying to compile it into a shared library to be used by Python ctypes. The compilation was not successful as I did on MacOS. After compiling, I ran python code, it gave Segmentation fault straight forwardly. Did anyone encounter same problem and know how to fix this?

Here is how I compile:

```
gcc -nostartfiles -o vrf.o -I/home/Data/libsodium/include -L/home/Data/libsodium/lib vrf.c
gcc -shared -fPIC -I/home/Data/libsodium/include -fPIC /home/Data/libsodium/lib/libsodium.a -L/home/Data/libsodium/lib -o vrf.so vrf.c
```

I tried both compile it from .c or .o file, but all failed. 
The link was to link the library i reference from installed location at `/home/Data/libsodium` 
While I compile it to executable `.o` file, linux gives error of

```
/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I added `-nostartfiles`, which raised another warning while compiling it to shared library

```
warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr ignored.
/usr/bin/ld: error in vrf.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created
```

The only difference is that on mac, the shared library is linked with static .a file, while on linux I tried the same compilation, but it failed.

Comment: What is the use of first gcc line? Doesn't it work with just second gcc line?

Comment: The first was compiling it into a executable file. There two approaches to generate shared object, one is directly from .c another is from .o, those are from my Google search o far.

Comment: `gcc -shared -fPIC -I/home/Data/libsodium/include -o vrf.so vrf.c -l:/home/Data/libsodium/lib/libsodium.a`? The (1st) error suggests `-shared` not being passed.

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/home/Data/libsodium/lib/libsodium.a

Comment: I did tried before -l: just doesnot work here

Comment: Downvoted the question: you *don't* have a segmentation fault. And your problem is during *linking*, which is different from *compiling*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Furious activity is no substitute for understanding. You appear to flail around with trying different command-line flags *at random*, and chances of stumbling on the correct flags this way are slim.

The correct command line you want is (almost what you had):

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -I/home/Data/libsodium/include -o vrf.so vrf.c /home/Data/libsodium/lib/libsodium.a
```

Note that `libsodim.a` *must* follow `vrf.c`, because that's [how UNIX linkers work](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking).

However, above command will not work, because `libsodium.a` itself contains non-`PIC` code.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. You can re-build `libsodium.a` with `-fPIC` flag, or
2. You can use `libsodium.so` and make `vrf.so` depend on that. Assuming `libsodium.so` is also installed in `/home/Data/libsodium/lib`, the correct command for that would be:

   `gcc -shared -fPIC -I/home/Data/libsodium/include \
     -L/home/Data/libsodium/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/Data/libsodium/lib \
    -o vrf.so vrf.c -lsodium`

Comment: Hi, man. sorry for the late reply. I have solved the problem. Your first solution is right. I built the libsodium.a with -fPIC and it worked. i dont know why the dynamic .so library just not work here. I did install again and link with .a succeed. Cheers